# oracle case statement return multiple character

Tags: sql, oracle, case

Hello please correct my query

---

```
select * from table S1
WHERE  S1.stu ='12345'
AND S1.sem = (Select Case When col2 > col4 Then col2 Else col4 End From table2)
And S1.met1 in  (case when (S1.sem = 1) then ('1', 'D', 'F' )
                      when (S1.sem = 2) then ('1', '5', '7',  )
                      when (S1.sem = 3) then ('1',  'D', 'F' )
                      else s1.sem end);
```

case should be used because of union with tables.
am getting

> Error: missing keyword

for this query

Comment: What is your expected results? or wat is the error in the query.. you need add more information to your question

Answer (score 6):

That is not how `case` works.  It is a *scalar* expression that returns only one value.

Replace it with basic logic:

```
where ( (S1.sem = 1 and s1.met1 in ('1', 'D', 'F' ) ) or
        (S1.sem = 2 and S1.met1 in ('1', '5', '7') ) or
        (S1.sem = 3 and s1.met1 in ('1', 'D', 'F' ) ) or
        (s1.sem not in (1, 2, 3) and s1.met1 = s1.sem)
      )
```

I would comment that based on the values you are using, it would seem that `s1.sem` is a number and `s1.met1` is a character.  For me, it is quite suspicious when a number is being compared to a string.